TV-series about a man getting an item that made him look into the past
I'm looking for a certain series that I have seen an episode of a long time ago, but I can't remember its name.
The series was about something supernatural. A man was given some sort of item (I think it was a necklace or something) and with that item he could see things that happened in the past (or future). 
I think one of his parents gave him the item when they died, I also remember him being in a room filled with items, every item was linked to a special event (like a sword that killed a certain creature) or special books.
What also came in mind when thinking about this series, was the man standing in some kind of forest, when he held up the amulet (or worn it) he suddenly saw a train coming his way (which was not there in his actual time).

That's very similar to the "supernatural" show, Constantine.
In the first episode there was a pendant that makes you see the past (And it happened to be a train that wasn't there like in your description)

It was given to him by the other character's father, not his own.
Also, he had a "hideout" where a lot of ancient/dangerous artifact were kept.
This is a relatively new show though.

@Luke Also "the room filled with items" makes me think of The Librarian movies and tv show. Also check Warehouse 13 and The Dresden Files out.

Thats it!!! Thank you so much!

Constatine is what I was looking for, thank you madmada!

No problem! Glad I could help.

It was shaping up to be a decent show, too bad they killed it so early.
